# Как повторно запустить таймер после его остановки?

Tags: kotlin, java-timer, compose-desktop

Подскажите, как после остановки таймера `timer.cancel()` снова запустить его?

```
val timer = Timer()
Column {
    Button(onClick = {
        timer.cancel()
    }) {
        Text("Stop")
    }
    Button(onClick = {
        myTimer(timer)
    }) {
        Text("Start")
    }
}

fun myTimer(timer: Timer){
    timer.schedule(delay = 0, period = 1000) {
        println("Timer")
    }
}
```

При таком коде у меня выходит ошибка:

```
Timer already cancelled.
```

Comment: Не использовать таймеры, а использовать вместо них `LaunchedEffect`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации к методу [`schedule`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,long,long)) сказано, что метод бросает `IllegalStateException`, если таймер был отменен. То есть повторно запустить таймер нельзя, создавайте новый объект таймера.

Например, это можно сделать так:

```kotlin
var timer by remember { mutableStateOf<Timer?>(null) }
Column {
    Button(onClick = {
        timer?.cancel()
        timer = null
    }) {
        Text("Stop")
    }
    Button(onClick = {
        if (timer == null) {
            timer = scheduleTimer()
        }
    }) {
        Text("Start")
    }
}
```

Создание нового экземпляра `Timer` и его запуск:

```kotlin
fun scheduleTimer(): Timer {
    val timer = Timer()
    timer.schedule(delay = 0, period = 1000) {
        println("Timer")
    }
    return timer
}
```

Comment: тут подсказали использовать `LaunchedEffect` -[vitidev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/191496/vitidev) вместо `Timer`  я новичок в `kotlin`   подскажите что лучше использовать

Comment: Ваш текущий вопрос задан про конкретную ошибку, которая возникает при использовании Timer. В нем не сказано, что вы бы хотели использовать что-то другое. Поэтому, заведите [новый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), подробно напишите какую проблему вы хотите решить. При необходимости в новом вопросе можете оставить ссылку на этот вопрос.